# Sorting values from argv

Tags: c, sorting

I have a lost of strings in argv and I would like to sort it. I am doing the sort with strcmp and strcpy.

How can I convert the const char** to a char array which I can use in my sort function?

```
void sort(const char** sl, int n) {

   char s[n][20], t[20];
   int i, j;

   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
         if (strcmp(s[j - 1], s[j]) > 0) {
            strcpy(t, s[j - 1]);
            strcpy(s[j - 1], s[j]);
            strcpy(s[j], t);
         }
      }
   }

   printf("\nStrings in order are : ");
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      printf("\n%s", s[i]);

}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
  sort(argv+1, argc-1);
  printf("Files: %i\n", argc-1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you compare the strings in `s1` with the *uninitialized* array `s[j]`.

Comment: I am not comparing anything yet, because I don't know how to convert from const char** to char[]...

Comment: In `sort` you have the expression `strcmp(s[j - 1], s[j])`, when you first call the function `s[j]` will be uninitialized, leading to the UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive what you want with standart `qsort` function.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int string_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}

void print_args(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("original:\n");
    print_args(argc, argv);

    qsort(argv, argc, sizeof(char *), string_cmp);

    printf("sorted:\n");
    print_args(argc, argv);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Test:**

```
$ ./String-Sort 432 123456 bhello ahello ch
```

**Output:**

```
original:
./String-Sort
432
123456
bhello
ahello
ch
sorted:
./String-Sort
123456
432
ahello
bhello
ch
```

But if still want your own function you just need to initialize array `s`, like this

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    strcpy(s[i], sl[i]);
}
```

Add this before your sort loop. But you need to be sure that length of every input string is less than 20, or you need to allocate more memory for strings.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it does not work as I need it, the strings I need to be sorted are like this a.1 a.2 a.3 a.4 - a.10 and it always gets sorted like a.1 a.10 a.2....

Comment: @Merl thats how ``strcmp`` works, with your approach you'll still recive result like this. Use ``strverscmp`` to achive right number comparation.